# Symfony - Doctrine how distinct SUM from JOIN?

Tags: symfony, sum, doctrine

I'm working on Symfony 3.4 and I have some troubles on a query, I will try to explain clearly !

I have 3 entities `Website`, `Mission`, `Gain` with :

```
Website OneToMany Mission
Mission OneToMany Gain
```

I have a `price` field in `Gain` entity

I need to `SUM` the `price` value for each `Gain` for each Website, but in my case it doesn't work.

In my example I have :

- 1 `Website`
- 3 `Mission` (linked to the `Website`)
- 1 `Gain` for each `Mission` (linked to `Mission`) with values in `price` : 100, 200, 300

This is my query (w is Website, m is Mission, g is Gain):

```
$builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('w');
$builder->innerJoin('w.missions', 'm');
$builder->innerJoin('m.gains', 'g', 'WITH','g.user = w.user');
$builder->select('w', 'SUM(g.price) as gain');
$builder->addSelect('COUNT(distinct m) as nbMissions');

$results = $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

With this query, I have in the SUM result `gain` the value 1800 instead of 600.

In fact it is the good result but multiplied by the number of missions (600*3). In `nbMissions` I have 3.

Do you know how can I have the right result ?

Thanks !

Comment: you could consider use group by